# Ставится ли запятая после слова "луч"?

Tags: пунктуация

Луч(,) параллельный главной оптической оси после преломления в линзе(,) проходит через фокус.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно это предложение необходимо оформить так:
*Луч, **параллельный главной оптической оси,** после преломления в линзе проходит через фокус.*

Согласованное определение "параллельный главной оптической оси" (прилагательное "параллельный" с зависимыми словами), стоящее после определяемого слова "луч" (какой?), выделяется запятыми.

> 1. Обособляется согласованное определение, состоящее из нескольких слов и относящееся к предшествующему имени существительному.

В евклидовой геометрии через точку проходит только одна прямая, **параллельная заранее указанной прямой,** а в геометрии Лобачевского — много таких прямых. [В. А. Успенский. Апология математики, или О математике как части духовной культуры // Новый Мир, 2007]

[Обособление согласованных определений](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_174#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5,%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83.)
[О тонкой линзе](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/fizika/8-klass/izuchaem-svetovye-iavleniia-131515/linza-fokusnoe-rasstoianie-linzy-postroenie-izobrazhenii-163989/re-96cc846e-0817-45e1-963e-21a7b1c4ebbf)